# What was the intention of the character after closing the door at the ending?

Tags: ending, sicario-day-of-the-soldado

Spoilers about *Sicario: Day of the Soldado* ahead!

I am confused as to what is the real intention of Alejandro with Miguel at the ending scene of the movie, Miguel seems scared to see him, and he loses all his bad ass attitude immediately. Is he going to rape Miguel, kill or recruit him?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a way to open a new series of movies, making Miguel a new antiheroe.

Comment: could be, but do you have any support for this statement?